# Advancing a progress bar during speech synthesis using Swift 2.0 (OS X)

Tags: swift, macos, speech-synthesis

I am trying to advance a determinate progress bar in 5.0 increments while the speech synthesizer is reading a block of text. This is the code I have (which is not working):

```
if speechSynthesizer.speaking == false {
    if let contents = textView.string where !contents.isEmpty {
        speechSynthesizer.startSpeakingString(contents)
        progressIndicator.hidden = false

        while speechSynthesizer.speaking == true {
            progressIndicator.incrementBy(5.0)
        }

        } else {
            speechSynthesizer.startSpeakingString("The document is empty.")
        }
   }

}
```

The progress bar displays but does not increment. If I take the "while..." out and just use the statement "progressIndicator.incrementBy(5.0)" then the progress increments, but only once.

Any suggestions on how to go about fixing this?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

-Syn-

Comment: You might need to do this on the main run loop for it show up

Comment: I'm extremely new to OS X programming. Could you please point me in the right direction as to accessing the main run loop in OS X? I don't see where it is in the generated source code...

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to move the code that updates your UI to the main run loop so the UI actually gets updated. So place that line inside a dispatch block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //insert UI code here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot along with the suggestion by Chris below.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate Protocol - Best it can offer is tell you which word its about to speak.

```
optional func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer,
                  willSpeakWord characterRange: NSRange,
                       ofString string: String)
```

As each word is spoken update the progress indicator

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer,
                      willSpeakWord characterRange: NSRange,
                           ofString string: String) {

let pc = (characterRange.location + characterRange.length) / string.length
progressIndicator.doubleValue = (pc * 100)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've given it a try but it seems like I am missing something. I implemented your function but the progress bar seems to not be moving. I'm sure it's just me and my lack of experience with the language. Thanks for answering me, I appreciate your time and help.